# Cannot find module on start of new Nodejitsu deployment

Tags: node.js, nodejitsu

I have a node application that runs locally and when deploying to Nodejitsu via `jitsu deploy`, the CLI reports a successful deployment.  However, when actually logging in to look at the application via the web based interface and attempting to activate the snapshot, the start fails with the following error:-

```
err Wed, 05 Nov 2014 14:10:37 GMT 
err Wed, 05 Nov 2014 14:10:37 GMT module.js:340
err Wed, 05 Nov 2014 14:10:37 GMT throw err;
err Wed, 05 Nov 2014 14:10:37 GMT Error: Cannot find module '/opt/run/snapshot/package/js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
err Wed, 05 Nov 2014 14:10:37 GMT ^
```

The trouble I am having, is the vagueness of the error.  What is '/opt/run/snapshot/package/js'? Is there a way of getting more detail out of Nodejitsu so I can see what maybe causing the problem? Is this something anyone else has had?

I can return to this question with more information if requested.

Help, as always, appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this. The problem was in my `packages.json` I had the following:-

```
   "scripts": {
        "start": "js server",
        "postinstall": "bower install",
        "test": "make test-cov"
    },
```

`js` is of course not recognised by Nodejitsu on run. I found, by changing it to:-

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
},
```

I had no problems.

A note to future Nodejitsu deployers, `postinstall` runs locally -- not on the server; therefore remove `bower_components` from your `.gitignore` if you need bower components on nodejitsu.

Hope this helps any adventurers who wander by.